# Discord.js: "if (message.channel.name === '')" not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot not respond if the message isn't in a channel, for some reason using

```js
if (message.channel.name === '')
```

doesn't work. I can see the channel  name by using if I console log it, so I don't understand why it's not working, and I get no errors in the console.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As @Padd mentioned in his answer, it looks like the `name` property does not exists on the `channel` object

Comment: @Marc No it does, it just doesn't work with if(!) for some reason.

Comment: And why is this not official documented ? did you tried `==` instead of `===` ?

Comment: You need allow trigger in specific channel?

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type) :

```
 if(msg.channel.type === 'text') { ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Add some additional information/code to your question